# BAföG financial support for European students?

Tags: masters, funding, germany

Are European students (Italian more specifically) entitled for getting the financial support BAföG to pursue an MSc Degree in a German University?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but the answer is yes, under certain conditions, which are laid down in BAföG par. 8: if you've lived legally in Germany for five years, if your spouse or parent(s) are working Work in Germany, or if you've worked in Germany for at least six months. See https://www.bafoeg-rechner.de/FAQ/bafoeg-fuer-auslaenderinnen.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EU citizens can get Bafög but you have to fulfill some requirements that link you to Germany, for example:

- have been living in Germany for over 5 years
- your parents or spouse is working in Germany
- you have been working in Germany before

You can find the full list here: [In german though](https://www.bafoeg-rechner.de/FAQ/bafoeg-fuer-auslaenderinnen.php)

If this is not applicable for you, you can try the [DAAD](https://www.daad.de/en/) (German Academic Exchange Program) which has an extensive selection of scholarships for students coming from or to Germany.